# passing argument 1 of 'recievematrix' from incompatible pointer type

Tags: c, windows

```
#include<stdio.h>

Funtions prototypes
int functiondouble(int b);
void notreturnanything(int a, int b);
void byreference(int *b);
void receivevector(int v[]);
void recievematrix(int m[][1]);

int main() {
    int c;
    printf("%d\n",functiondouble(5));
    notreturnanything(3,9);
    c = 0;
    byreference(&c);
    printf("%d\n",c);
    int a[10], b[3][4];
    receivevector(a);
    recievematrix((int)b); // <----- warning: passing argument 1 of 'recievematrix' from incompatible pointer type [enabled by default]|
    return 0;
}

int functiondouble(int b) {
    int a;
    a = 2*b;
    return a;
}

void notreturnanything(int a, int b) {
    printf("%d\n",a+b);
}
```

Is ok. The two funtion no problems. They receive a single value without problems.

```
void byreference(int *b) {
    *b = 7;
}

void receivevector(int v[]) {
    scanf("%d", &v[0]);
}

void recievematrix(int m[][1]) {
    scanf("%d", &m[1][1]);
}
```

This is a prove to see how work the arrays in C, but a pulls mistake and not where is the error.

Comment: suggest, for readability of the code, to use 'camel' case for function and variable names

Comment: the returned value from scanf(), and family of functions, should always be checked to assure the operation was successful

Comment: on this call (and perhaps on similar calls) 'recievematrix((int)b);' the called function is expecting a pointer to an int, not an int.  perhaps use: 'recievematrix((int * )b);'

Comment: all any of the sub functions actually receive is a pointer, the body of the function can handle that pointer however it wants.  so, for instance, this prototype and declaration: 'void recievematrix(int m[][1]); is really: 'void recievematrix(int * m);'  no change is needed in the body of the function.  however, in either case, a 'pointer to int' must be passed when the function is called, not an 'int'.

Answer (score 1):

This ...

```
int b[3][4];
```

... declares an array of three arrays of four `int`s.  Given that declaration, in most expressions the array name `b` is converted to a pointer to its first element; that is, a pointer to an array of four `int`s (`int (*)[4]`);

This ...

```
int m[][1]
```

... declares an array of an unspecified number of arrays of one `int`.  In the argument list of a function, it is converted to a pointer to an array of one `int` (`int (*)[1]`).

`int (*)[4]` is not compatible with `int (*)[1]`.  To resolve the warning (which you certainly should do) without changing the type of variable `b`, change the signature of `receivematrix()` to

```
void recievematrix(int m[][4]);
```

or

```
void recievematrix(int (*m)[4]);
```

or even

```
void recievematrix(int m[3][4]);
```

For that matter, even

```
void recievematrix(int m[17][4]);
```

would silence the warning, though I wouldn't recommend using it.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
void recievematrix(int m[3][4])
```

And

```
recievematrix(b);
```